# RegExp заменить, если больше, чем 1 совпадение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно проверять строку и, если там больше одной запятой или точки, удалять дополнительные. Ну и разрешить только числа, это работает.

```
event.target.value.toString().replace(/[^0-9]\.,.{2}/g, '')
```

`,.{2}` вроде должно это работать, не понимаю, что не так

`,.{2,}` тоже пробовал и не получилось

Могу писать бесконечно точек и запятых. А нужна только точка `или` запятая. Если совпадение есть, то ни точку ни запятую больше писать нельзя. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было оставлять только одну точку или запятую?
Поведение аналогичное с `<input type="number">`

**UPDATE**

Решение нашёл здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input

Comment: Ни примера входных данных, ни выходных. Вы пять лет участник ruSO, а так и не научились оформлять вопросы. Пичалько...

Answer (score 1):

В `RegExp` встроена "функция запоминания". То есть мы ищем какое-то совпадение, запоминаем его и дальше ищем по нему.
В примере ниже мы ищем символы `.` или `,`, запоминаем и при нахождении этого символа ещё раз удаляем его.

```js
const before = `,.,.,.,.,,......,,,,,..`;
console.log(`Before: '${before}'`); // Before: ',.,.,.,.,,......,,,,,..'
const after = before.replace(/(?<match>[,.])(?=.*\k<match>)/g, ``);
console.log(`After: '${after}'`); // After: ',.'
```

[Подробнее об группах и обратных ссылок](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Backreferences#sect1).

---

Вот как можно это реализовать как будто запрет ввода при повторе.
Попробуйте вводить несколько `.` или `,` в примере ниже:

```js
const textareaTest = document.querySelector(`textarea#test`);
let before = textareaTest.value;
textareaTest.addEventListener(`beforeinput`, (event) => {
  before = textareaTest.value;
});
textareaTest.addEventListener(`input`, (event) => {
  if (/(?<match>[,.])(?=.*\k<match>)/g.test(textareaTest.value)) {
    textareaTest.value = before;
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="test" placeholder="Повтори запятую если сможешь" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
```

Comment: Ваш код удаляет прошлый символ и добавляет новый. А нужно просто запретить, если больше, чем 1 совпадение или точки или запятой.  Нужно поведение, как в input type="number". Там нельзя много точек или запятых ставить

Comment: @РомаХр "Запретить" это чтобы пользователь не смог вводить? Так проверяйте строку с помощью моего выражения через `Regex.test()` и при совпадении запретите ввод.

Comment: @РомаХр дополнил ответ примером. По идеи это то, что вы хотите.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, то нужно не заменять значение, а не допускать некорректный ввод изначально. Тогда вопрос должен звучать, как "Ограничить ввод цифрами и одним разделителем" или "Имитация логики input с типом number".

```js
numeric.addEventListener('beforeinput', function(ev) {
  if (['insertText', 'insertFromPaste', 'insertFromDrop'].includes(ev.inputType)) {
    if (!/^\d*[,.]?\d*$/.test(ev.data) || (/[,.]/g.test(ev.data) && /[,.]/g.test(this.value))) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numeric">
```

Comment: Да, верно, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В итоге вам нужно допускать только цифры и символы "." и ",", остальное удалить? и пробелы тоже?

```
.toString().replace(/[^.,0-9]/g, '')
```

.

А вот повторения между символами "." и "," я бы предложил сделать отдельным выражением, оставив только первое вхождение:

```
.toString().replace(/(\.|,)(\.|,)+/g, "$1")
```

Comment: Ваш код работает, но можно поставить много точек и запятых после. Нужно поведение, как в input type="number". Там нельзя много точек или запятых ставить

Comment: не понял. После чего поставить много точек и запятых?

var aaa = "4637...647....";
aaa = aaa.toString().replace(/(\.|,)(\.|,)+/g, "$1");

console.log(aaa);